# Python Selenium Webdriver: Drag and drop failing

Tags: python, firefox, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver

Drag and drop feature is not working in test framework. It is working for last 6 months and all of a sudden this feature alone of Selenium is not working.

Previously my selenium version 2.33 and upgraded to latest 2.41.0. Still it is not working

All other actions say double click, filling text box etc are working fine.

I am not getting any error from selenium that drag and drop is failing but the object is not seen in the target.
I increased implicit time, and also inserted explicit sleep but it is not working.

firefox version is 16.

Did anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is drag and drop working manually when you open page in firefox? It may happen page has changed.

Comment: Is there a way to uninstall Selenium Webdriver in linux? I want to reinstall an older version ie 2.33 which worked for me. Can you please let me know the syntax for installing specific version of selenium in linux?

Comment: You need not to uninstall/install selenium. While running you add selenium jar file in classpath. How are you running tests? Which IDE are you using.

Comment: Actually I installed python selenium webdriver on linux machine so I didnt use jar file. In Selenium website previous release of java are present. Where can I previous versions of Python?https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount